# How to get Body and Headers from webhook callback in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-standard

How to get webhook request header and body, Body coming fine when using [FromBody].

What class can we use to get both headers and body

please check my below code.

```
public class WebhookController : ApiController
{
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("webhookcallback")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetWebhookData([FromBody]object response)
        {
            var _request = Request;
            var headers = _request.Headers; // custom header values not coming
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "SUCCESS");
        }
}
```

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: What sort of custom headers are you providing in the HTTP request? Are they Content related headers (and might appear in `Request.Content.Headers`)?

Comment: In the webhook call back vendor sending header 'event-type', and body.. based on 'event-type' I need to implement the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Using below code to get header value

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
if (Request.Headers.TryGetValues("event-type", out headerValues))
{
    string eventType = headerValues.First();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).